# What's RPC api to get unconfirmed balance?

Tags: rpc, api

Is it possible to get unconfirmed balance through the rpc REST api?

I didn't find any on the official documentation: https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-balance